# Query regarding XML to XML conversion

Tags: xml, xslt

There are two ways in which figures are placed in my input xml file(Note:Very basic form of my input):

1.For 1 figure:

```
<xref id="F2">Figure 2</xref>
```

2.For more than 1 figure:

```
<xref id="F5">Figures 5</xref>-<xref id="F8">8</xref>
```

As can be seen above, the xref ids 6 and 7 are missed.

Now in my output xml file, first one has to remain as it is, but the second one has to be changed to the following:

```
<xref id="F5 F6 F7 F8">Figures 5-8<xref>
```

The conversion code has to be generic. Don't know if this is possible. Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to specify the parent element for the <xref> elements. Is the second form always a single pair, with a hyphen (-) floating as a text node in between? And is "Figure" or "Figures" variable or fixed?

Comment: The parent element is a `p` tag. And for the second form, the hyphen will always be at the same place as shown above and the `Figures` variable is fixed for multiple `xref`s.

Comment: @laune, the parent element may not necessarily be a `p` tag. But in my current case it is.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's an XSLT, tested with the XML as shown, using saxon 9 he. It's now based on

being the parent, but that could be fixed for anything containing xref.

```
$ java -cp /extra/saxon/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:fig.xml -xsl:fig.xsl
```

fig.xml:

```
<data>
  <p>
    <xref id="2">Figure 2</xref>
    <xref id="5">Figures 5</xref>-<xref id="8">8</xref>
    <xref id="10">Figure 10</xref>
    <xref id="15">Figures 15</xref>-<xref id="18">18</xref>
  </p>
</data>
```

**Modified 3rd time according to revised/detailed specs** -- fig.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xy="/x/y"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xy xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="*">  
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="xy:preF" as="xs:string*">
  <xsl:param name = "nums" as="xs:integer*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$nums">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('F',.)"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="xref[starts-with(text(), 'Figure ')]">  
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref[starts-with(text(), 'Figures ')]">
  <xsl:variable name="a" as="xs:integer" select="substring( @id, 2 ) cast as xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:variable name="b" as="xs:integer" select="substring( following-sibling:: [name()='xref'][1]/@id, 2 ) cast as xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:variable name="Fab" as="xs:string*" select="xy:preF($a to $b)"/>
  <xref>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Fab"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Figures ',$a,'-',$b)"/>
  </xref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xref[not( starts-with(text(), 'Figure'))]">
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Bro this is fine but what if the parent is not `p`? And if the input is this:                                                    `<p>
   <xref id="3">Figure 3</xref>...some text..<xref id="5">Figures 5</xref>-<xref id="8">8</xref>
  </p>`

Comment: Well, I was asking about this. So the 's' in "Figures" is the only indicator that says that another <xref> is to come? Sure, just give me time, am in a meeting right now.

Comment: Its working. Hey I have updated the input. I have found a sample input with @id having a prefix F. How will `$a to $b` work now? Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The following styleshet uses XSLT version 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[.='-'][preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='xref']][following-sibling::*[1][name()='xref']]">
        <xsl:variable name="lower" select="preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='xref']/@id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="upper" select="following-sibling::*[1][name()='xref']/@id"/>
        <xref>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:for-each select="(xs:integer($lower) to xs:integer($upper))">
                    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('F', .)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='xref']"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::*[1][name()='xref']"/>
        </xref>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xref[following-sibling::text()[.='-']]|xref[preceding-sibling::text()[.='-']]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to an input like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <p>
        <xref id="2">Figure 2</xref>
    </p>
    <p>
        <xref id="5">Figures 5</xref>-<xref id="8">8</xref>
    </p>
</data>
```

the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <p>
      <xref id="2">Figure 2</xref>
   </p>
   <p>
      <xref id="F5 F6 F7 F8">Figures 5-8</xref>
   </p>
</data>
```

Comment: This is working fine. Hey I have updated the input. I have found a sample input with @id having a prefix F. How will `(xs:integer($lower) to xs:integer($upper))` work now? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen Yikes, I must have messed up your stylesheet while trying to patch mine. Sorry.